# How to use a package manager to install and load a unique driver

Tags: apt, package-management, drivers, kernel-modules

I'm no expert on Linux package managers.

If I develop a completely new Kernel driver for an embedded device, I can add this into the Linux image and load it on startup with `insmod` or `modprobe` etc.

However, how could I make this driver available to be installed, and loaded by anyone using a package manager `apt-get` from the Linux terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend packaging your module and relying on [DKMS](https://github.com/dell/dkms) to take care of the actual compilation and installation — this ensures that your module is rebuilt whenever a new kernel is installed.

To go about this, you need to

- provide a `Makefile` capable of building your module (as usual for kernel modules)
- describe your module in a `dkms.conf` file, *e.g.*

  ```
  PACKAGE_VERSION="1.2.3"
  PACKAGE_NAME="my_module"
  CLEAN="make clean"
  BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="my_module"
  BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/src"
  DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/extra"
  MAKE[0]="make KVER=$kernelver -C ${dkms_tree}/${PACKAGE_NAME}/${PACKAGE_VERSION}/build"
  AUTOINSTALL="yes"
  ```
- package your module without building it — your `debian/rules` file would look something like

  ```make
  #!/usr/bin/make -f

  PACKAGE_NAME=$(shell grep PACKAGE_NAME= dkms.conf | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d\" -f2)
  PACKAGE_VERSION=$(shell grep PACKAGE_VERSION= dkms.conf | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d\" -f2)
  export PACKAGE_NAME PACKAGE_VERSION

  %:
    dh $@

  # Nothing to configure, build or auto-install (this all happens after
  # installation using dkms)
  override_dh_auto_configure:
  override_dh_auto_build:
  override_dh_auto_install:
  ```

  and your `debian/install` file would declare the various source files you need to install, *e.g.*

  ```sh
  #!/bin/sh

  for dir in src Makefile; do
      echo ${dir} /usr/src/${PACKAGE_NAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}
  done
  ```
- build-depend on `dh-sequence-dkms` which takes care of everything else.

Take a look at my [`ddcci`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ddcci-driver-linux/) package for a working example.